# Set a general theme for progressDialog?

Tags: android

How can I set a theme for all progress bars that I create in my Project ?

This is my style :

```
<style name="MyTheme.ProgressDialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/anyColor</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

And I set it manually in the constructor of each progressDialog I create :

```
loadingDialog = new ProgressDialog(this, R.style.MyTheme_ProgressDialog);
```

Can I set the theme to be the default for all progress dialogs I create without changin it in the constructor each time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ProgressDialog` has only one more constructor [ProgressDialog(Context)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/app/ProgressDialog.java#ProgressDialog.%3Cinit%3E%28android.content.Context%29) which internaly use `com.android.internal.R.style.Theme_Dialog_Alert` style. There is no way you can override it. By contrast you can create a simple subclass of ProgressDialog and create a constructor with it which will use your style. That way you will not have to specify style every time.

```
public class MyProgressDialog extends ProgressDialog {
    public MyProgressDialog(Context context) {
        super(context, R.style.your_custom_style);
    }

    public MyProgressDialog(Context context, int theme) {
        super(context, theme);
    }
}
```

Comment: still a new account without reps ... sorry :D

Answer (score 0):

set in style.xml your progress style like this:

```
<style name="progressBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Large">
<item name="android:progressBarStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Large</item>
</style>
```

then in all progressbars set style attribute as follow:

```
  <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading_spinner_1"
        style="@style/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

Comment: Notice that this way you style only `ProgressBar` while `ProgressDialog` consists of more than just `ProgressBar`.

Comment: You are right, this answer correct for Progressbars.